# Can a druid use an action/attack granted by a spell while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape

Some spells like *Investiture of Flame, Investiture of Ice, Investiture of Wind, Investiture of Stone and Dragon's Breath* have effects that grant a damaging spell-like action. Is it possible to cast the spell on yourself and maintain concentration, then enter Wild Shape and use those actions?

I'm aware that there are probably many more spells like these that grant actions, and some, like *Dragon's Breath*, would need a multi-class. I picture a tiny spider throwing tornadoes or causing earthquakes or spewing fire.

I'm also aware that it was unofficially tweeted that a dragonborn can still use their racial Breath Weapon trait in Wild Shape.

Comment: Related: "[Can a Druid cast the Flame Blade spell, then use the blade while Wild Shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142998)"

Comment: Related: [Can my Dragonborn Druid use their breath weapon in wild shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105225/can-my-dragonborn-druid-use-their-breath-weapon-in-wild-shape) (I assume you meant one of the tweets quoted there? If so, you should edit the link to the relevant tweet into your post.)

Answer (score 10):

### You can use any effect of a spell that you have already cast before going into wild shape.

The text of [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) states, in part (emphasis mine):

> - You can’t cast spells, and your ability to speak or take any action that requires hands is limited to the capabilities of your beast form. **Transforming doesn’t break your concentration on a spell you’ve already cast, however, or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell, such as *call lightning*, that you’ve already cast.**

This does not limit it in any way other than that you cannot cast spells, and if the action requires you to speak or use a human-like body part. So if you have already cast *Investiture of Flame*, you get all of the benefits for as long as you maintain concentration as your itsy bitsy spider (In Soviet Underdark, Spider kill YOU with fire).

Comment: I think a notable possible exception would be spells such as *shadow blade* and *flame blade* which either are actually weapons or are very similar to weapons and seem to require a hand, which not all Wild Shape forms have. Such as discussed here: [Can a Druid cast the Flame Blade spell, then use the blade while Wild Shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142998)

Comment: The Ape is a notable exception that often allows more synergy between Wild Shape and class features, not just a Druid's but with other classes: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-a-druid-in-ape-wildshape-use-weapons , 
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53188/can-a-druid-monk-make-unarmed-strikes-while-wild-shaped/53199#53199 , 
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165425/can-a-druid-who-is-wild-shaped-into-an-ape-cast-spells-that-only-have-somatic-co.